# react native amplify configuration missing required auth properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I have a react native project using 'AWS' amplify.

I already did the configuration and added `auth` and pushed...

But I'm getting the error:

> Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. The configuration
> object is missing required auth properties.This error is typically
> caused by one of the following scenarios:
>
> 1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`? See
>    https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup
>    for more information
> 2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see
>    (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js)
>    for help upgrading Amplify packages.

So I pushed already, but how to fix error number 2?

Or what else can this mean? Thanks in advance.